# Magento2.1.7 (Mailchimp_Error): Resource Not Found : The requested resource could not be found

Tags: magento2, mailchimp

I am trying to install the mailchimp extension via composer. When enable the mailchimp extension getting the **MailChimpLogger.INFO: Resource Not Found : The requested resource could not be found** error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1. Download extension [here](https://marketplace.magento.com/mailchimp-mc-magento2.html).
2. Follow the manual steps for installation.

   Upload, Setup Upgrade, Static Content Deploy, Clear Cache.

Thank you,